# Standard deviation calculation where sometimes there is no data

Tags: excel, vba, stdev

I want cell W4 to be the standard deviation of range C to V.

Some of the rows will be empty and thus not able to calculate a standard deviation.

I would like to return a blank cell or better to delete the row.

```vb
For i = 1 to 1000
    Range("W4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range(Range("C4").Cells(i, 1), Range("V4").Cells(i, 1))), "")
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following code the cells in column W will be untouched in case  `Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range(Range("C4").Cells(i, 1), Range("V4").Cells(i, 1))), "")` runs into an error.

```
On Error Resume Next
Range("W4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range(Range("C4").Cells(i, 1), Range("V4").Cells(i, 1))), "")
On Error GoTo 0
```

If you want to make sure that the cell in column W will be blank you could use the following code

```
On Error Resume Next
    Range("W4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range(Range("C4").Cells(i, 1), Range("V4").Cells(i, 1))), "")
    lsterr = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    If lsterr > 0 Then
        Range("W4").Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
    End If
```

And if you want to delete the complete row you have to adjust the loop as well like that

```
For i = 1000 To 1 Step -1
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("W4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range(Range("C4").Cells(i, 1), Range("V4").Cells(i, 1))), "")
    lsterr = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    If lsterr > 0 Then
        Range("W4").Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```